# How to sum values for each day in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to make  two columns one that has date and the other that has sum for the number of violations occurred on that day. Have a look at the data below.

[image: see the image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY({B:C}; "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col1)''")
```